# Organization GitHub Pages with automatic links to repository GH pages

Tags: github-pages

Our organization page has a repository https://github.com/ocbe-uio/ocbe-uio.github.io where we could create a file (README.md or index.md, for example) to provide content to https://ocbe-uio.github.io/

Then we have several repositories, some of which have their own deployed pages (e.g. ocbe-uio.github.io/matlab2r/, https://ocbe-uio.github.io/TruncExpFam/, https://ocbe-uio.github.io/trajpy/). I would like to have these linked on the aforementioned main page.

Setting up the repository pages is up to each individual maintainer, but it would be very nice to have the top-level repository (https://github.com/ocbe-uio/ocbe-uio.github.io) automatically detect those so I don't have to go through our 30+ repositories and see which ones have a GH Page set up then manually add those to the home page.

I've read through the [GitHub Pages documentation](https://pages.github.com/) and couldn't find anything I could use. Tried adding one of the repos as a submodule, but that didn't do anything. Any ideas?